# mySQL min() and max() query array echoing zero

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, sql-server

I have a table set up with 5 columns:

> user_id, 5k, 10k, halfmarathon, and marathon.

I want to display the user's best times on a user page for each distance of run. The user will be able to update any of the times which creates a new row and the rest of the columns are set to null. So for example,

Row 1 is:

> user_id: 5, 5k: null, 10k: 45:00, half: null, marathon: null.

Then the user runs another 10k and gets a better time, plus wants to update their 5k time :

Row 2 is then:

> user_id: 5, 5k: 15:53, 10k: 40:40, half: null, marathon: null.

When I run the following SQL query

```
$query = "SELECT MIN(5k), MIN(10k), MIN(halfmartahon), MIN(marathon)
        FROM Times
        WHERE user_id = ".$userID."
        GROUP BY user_id";
$db->query($query);
//Assign Result Set
$user_benchmarks = $db->single();`
```

I get an array that is correct when I `vardump()` (I am storing the times in seconds) :

> object(stdClass)#18 (4) { ["MIN(5k)"]=> string(3) "953" ["MIN(10k)"]=> string(4) "2440" ["MIN(halfmarathon)"]=> string(1) "0" ["MIN(marathon)"]=> string(1) "0" }

However, when I try to echo this, so `$user_benchmarks->5k` it doesn't show anything and when I run `print_r($user_benchmarks->5k)` it comes back as `NULL`.

Has anyone encountered this / know what's happening? I've also tried turning the string to an integer before printing it to no avail - still get `NULL`.

Comment: The property `5k`, shouldnt it be `MIN(5k)` ?

Comment: Normalise your schema. A database table is not a spreadsheet!

Comment: Is there any reason why your table is not like `user_id`, `race_type`, `time` ? It's probably going to save you a lot of nulls and make queries a lot more intuitive. Your question will also become a lot simpler to answer.

Comment: @apokryfos - i am pretty new to this so trying to figure it out as i go :-). this is a cool idea. could you give me an example how the query would work? if i reduced my table to 3 columns how would i extract all the MIN times for each user for each race type?

Comment: @HotWhiskey `SELECT user_id, race_type, MIN(time) FROM table GROUP BY user_id,race_type` and this will list all user/race type combinations and the minimum type for each. (You can also have where clauses to filter by e.g. user or race type)

Comment: @apokryfos - thank you :-) if i were to add another race type where instead of the min time i wanted to get the max is that do-able? this table is going to have benchmark-type workouts like run 20 minutes and record your amount of miles where for that we would want the most miles ran in 20 minutes. that's kind of why i laid it out like i did (other than not knowing better haha).

Comment: @HotWhiskey you could use `MAX(time)` instead or you could get both. Basically you could benefit from learning more SQL. It's going to be very useful to you. For example you can use any of the functions at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html (either instead of MIN or in addition to MIN. As other suggested it would be good to use an alias for the column names so you can access them easily in PHP.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use

```
SELECT MIN(5k) as 5k, 
       MIN(10k) as 10k, 
       MIN(halfmartahon) as halfmartahon, 
       MIN(marathon) as marathon
```

Comment: @Down voter : Can you please explain why this is not accepted?

Comment: Im not sure. But maybe you got downvote because you didnt explain what  was the problem. Also not sure if you can name a variable `5k` you probably need use backticks `\`5k\``

Comment: Actually I cannot use backticks in my answer since stackoverflow uses backticks for code alignment. Also it is not mandatory for this column other than reserved keywords.

Answer (score 0):

var_dump already showed you exactly what keys to use:

```
object(stdClass)#18 (4) { ["MIN(5k)"]=> string(3) "953"
                            ^^^^^^^
```

so why are you using

```
$user_benchmarks->5k
                 ^^^
```

?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the "5k" property of the $user_benchmarks object doesn't exist. You need to access the "MIN(5k)" property instead. So for example:

```
echo $user_benchmarks->{"MIN(5k)"};
```

On the other hand you can change the query to something like this:

```
SELECT MIN(5k) AS `5k`, MIN(10k) AS `10k` ...
```

Then you will be able to access properties "5k" and "10k" just like you wanted.

Comment: yes! thank you! The other guy responded first so I gave the answer to him but awesome. For some reason echoing with the ["MIN(5k)"] wasn't working but I want it as clean as I had above. Thank you!

Comment: @HotWhiskey I'm glad I could help. I edited my answer and fixed the first `echo` example, so it should work now.